# Manage many different onboarding flows

Tags: angular, navigation

We are developing an Angular application the requries the user to sign up and enter some data.

After the user signs up in our app, they start an onboarding where they go through various screens to enter/select data in order for the app to work.

Not only the order, but also which screens appear depends on various parameters like country the users are currently in, the selected app language, selections of the users etc. as they need different things from the app depending on these.

Currently after every step there are a bunch of if/else statements, to determine where the app will go next.

As you can imagine, this approach gets quickly out of hand as the app begins to support a bigger variety of user groups and has to offer more and more onboarding flows, that might also share some common screens used for many groups.
This leads to a lot of logic at the end of every step that gets all the parameters and then takes a decision and its easy to forget one of the many combinations of settings/choices/locations... when designing the flow.

Does someone have experience with a similar case and can give recommendations on how they navigate users through the different onboardings in a clear and expandable manner?

Answer (score 1):

On the top of my head, I can see two different solutions you might implement:

- The first one you define a common flow from start to finish and then, on each component/route, you define a guard that handles the logic that allows/disallows the user to enter that page. If the guard disallows it, navigate onto the next one.
- The second one you pre-define possible onboarding flows and save them anywhere (constants file for example). Then, according to some information about the logged-in user, you decide which flow to follow.

In both cases, I would have a specific service to handle all related logic. From saving the necessary inputs, to deciding where to navigate next. That way you avoid spreading a bunch of unnecessary logic across multiple components that don't need to know about it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I find the first point you mention interesting: In case the guard denies routing, would you do the redirecting directly in the guard or simply return false and handle it else where?

Comment: You could redirect directly in the guard and then return false.